# What are the possible return codes of bpf_filter(), in FreeBSD kernel? What does each return codes mean?

Tags: freebsd, tcpdump, bpf

What are the possible return codes of bpf_filter(), in FreeBSD kernel?

What does each return codes mean?

The [man page (link)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bpf_filter&apropos=0&sektion=9&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&format=html) is not clear on this issue.

The `bpf_filter()` function executes   the filter program starting at pc on
     the packet pkt. The wirelen argument is the length of the  original
     packet and buflen is the amount of data present.  The buflen value of `0`
     is special; it indicates that the pkt is actually a pointer to an mbuf
     chain (`struct mbuf *`).

#### Return Values

The `bpf_filter()` function returns `-1` (cast to an unsigned integer)  if there is no filter.  Otherwise, it returns the result of the filter program.

I am getting `65535` when there is a Match and `0` when there is no match. Not sure what is the meaning for the return value `65535`.

Can someone please explain the return code of `bpf_filter()` in detailed?

Answer (score 1):

The return value of bpf_filter() is the result of the filter program. The result being number of bytes of the packet being filtered to be copied to the buffer for the task (the filter return instruction value).

The value will be 0 if the packet does not match the filter.
If the packet matches the filter it will be the snapshot length (snaplen) that was defined in the pcap_open_ call.

The default value is 65535 bytes as the maximum size of a TCP packet is 64K (65535 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

The function `bpf_filter()` takes a pointer to a struct containing the BPF instructions as an argument (`pc` on the man page) and runs these on the packets to filter them.

> The bpf_filter() function returns -1 (cast to an unsigned integer) if
>   there is no filter.

We can check [in the source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/bsd/net/bpf_filter.c) that when `pc`, the structure that should contain the BPF instructions, is null, then `bpf_filter()` immediately returns `-1`, cast to a `u_int`:

```
if (pc == 0)
    /*
     * No filter means accept all.
     */
    return (u_int)-1;
```

**[Edited]** Internally, for a signed integer, `-1` would be stored as “the maximal value for a integer, minus one”. With 32 bits, since the return value here is cast to an unsigned integer, that would be `2^32 - 1`.
<strike>Since the return value here is cast to an unsigned integer, this is the value you obtain: `65535` equals to `2**16 - 1`, so `-1` cast to a unsigned 16 bit-long integer (a `u_int`). So I would tend to believe that when you see this `65535` value, you do not actually provide any BPF program to the function? Would that be consistant with you observations?</strike>

Now when there is a match:

> Otherwise, it returns the result of the filter program.

The result value of `bpf_filter()` is the result retreived from the BPF program. So when you get a `0` return value, it means that:

- Either your BPF program completed and returned `0`.
- Or possibly (even though this does not seem documented in the man page), an error was encountered while running the BPF program. Here is an example, also from the source:

  ```
  case BPF_ALU|BPF_DIV|BPF_X:
      if (X == 0)
          return 0;
      A /= X;
      continue;
  ```

“In the case of an arithmetic division, if the denominator `X` is null, then make `bpf_filter()` return `0`, else divide register `A` by register `X` and carry on to the next instruction”.

**[Edited]** (see comments) As you found out, the same applies for the `65535` value: it is the value you made your BPF program return.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.
 
u_int bpf_filter(const struct bpf_insn *pc, u_char *p, u_int wirelen, u_int buflen) 

you could see from above that the return value is of type " u_int" so its 32bit unsigned integer. when you cast -1 to unsigned 32 bit integer, then it is: 4294967295.

More over I have put few traces around "if(pc == 0)" block, where "-1" is returned. And from those traces I could see that it is not going to this "if" block at all.

I guess it should return the packet length in success case, but it is returning 65535 everytime when the match is hit.(my pkt len is 78)

Comment: Hmm I do not see why it would print the packet length anyway, it should be BPF return value. Since you can debug the function, then could you tell which “return” statement in `bpf_filter()` is actually used? Maybe that could help. Also, would that be possible to provide the BPF program you are using?

Comment: I found the issue, bpf_filter() is returning 65535 because I had specified 65535 for pcap open, as below:
pcap_open_dead(DLT_EN10MB, 65535);

Now, bpf_filter() returning 1, after replacing 65535 with 1.

Qeole, Thanks for your answer. It helped me in getting more clarity..

Comment: @KrishnamRajuraju: Great! That makes sense indeed. Happy to know I could help :-).